# Upload BPEL files to WSO2 BPS through the API

Tags: bpel, wso2-business-process

I would like to use the WSO2 BPS API to upload BPEL process files automatically (in bulk). How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use BPEL Uploader admin service for this purpose. This is available from 3.x. versions. You can view WSDL file for this service after changing **HideAdminServiceWSDLs** to **false** in carbon.xml. It is in `<BPS_HOME>`/repository/conf directory. You can view the wsdl file from the below link after restarting the server.

https://localhost:9443/services/BPELUploader?wsdl

For more information about this you can find [here](http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2015/11/wso2bps-uploading-bpel-archive-using.html). This link describes how to upload BPEL archive project using SOAP UI as well as CURL command line tool. Hope this resolves your issue.